# PhpStorm does not suggest table name in UPDATE query inside a PHP string

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2022.2.3

```
Build #PS-222.4345.15, built on October 5, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-50-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    run.processes.with.pty=TRUE

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    de.espend.idea.php.annotation (8.2.3)
    fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin (2022.1.234)
```

Inside a PHP file, it does not suggest table names for UPDATE query, but instead it does for INSERT INTO query.

[image]

Then, <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Have you set up a database connection? Is it up to date?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sure, as I stated, for "INSERT INTO" it suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's NOT detected as SQL yet -- not enough context info to treat the string context as SQL.

Having `INSERT INTO` at the start of a string is good enough (it's quite unique combo at the start of the string) but `UPDATE` is not -- too many possible false positives. For example, I do not see why would I need to see a table name completion/string treated as SQL statement if I need to write "Update linked records" or a similar text that starts with `UPDATE` word.

#### Possible solutions:

1. Use Intentions / Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter` on most keymaps or using a mouse on a light bulb icon) and choose `Inject language or reference` and then select the desired SQL there. This will temporarily inject SQL (lasts while the file is opened). Once the string will have enough context the permanent injection rule will naturally take over.

   [image]
2. Force-inject SQL with a comment (just before the string):

   ```php
   $sql = /** @lang SQL */"UPDATE ";
   ```

   [image]
3. Use HEREDOC/NOWDOC with specific `SQL` label -- will utilize the same forced injection (pros: multiline text, looks natural).

   ```php
   $sql = <<<SQL
   UPDATE 
   SQL;
   ```

   [image]
4. If you want that ALL strings that start with `UPDATE` (mind -- it's case insensitive) to have SQL auto-injected and you do not care about any possible false positive -- go and change (or better: make a copy so you do not screw up the original one) the Language Injection rule that is responsible for PHP.

   `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Language Injections` -- look at the following rule:

   [image]

   *NOTE: the syntax is RegEx alike but it's not RegEx.*

Comment: thanks, by writing this is enough to activate the suggestion: `$q = "UPDATE  SET ";` (I saw the regEx editing your suggested setting)